# How to leverage Intel GPU and Nvidia GPU at the same notebook computer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

Folks

I have a notebook with Intel and Nvidia GPUs.

two questions of the utilization of GPUs.

1. Can I use both Nvidia GPU Compute_0 and Compute_1?

   Looks Compute_1 always 0% of the utilization
2. Can I use both Intel and Nvidia GPU at the same time?

   Currently, the system is only using Nvidia GPU Compute_0 for AI training.

thank you.

right now, only run AI training on Nvidia GPU

Here is the GPU/ CPU performance from Win10:

[image: performance screen capture]

Comment: The Intel GPU has very little power compared to the NVidia one so it's not really worth using. If you need more GPU power, consider an external GPU (e.g. over USB 3.0 expansion chassis) where you can kit it out with whatever GPU you want, even a 2080ti.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use two GPU's simultaneously without bridging them. Even when bridging them, it would require you to use the same models and even then you would find about a 40% increase in productivity. This would be a computer architectural issue instead of a programming one. And, in your case, since you have 2 different GPU's, it is not feasible. To optimize the performance of your GPU with your program, look into CUDA. Here is the documentation: 
[1](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/)

Answer (score 0):

Your system is running as intended. You are using the correct GPU. It is nonsensical to use your integrated graphics. It won't do anything.

Comment: thank you. just curious if I can leverage the GPU resources in my NB.

Comment: Makes sense, if you could click the check mark next to the answer to indicate to others that this was the answer, that would be helpful. That way others will know the answer to your question.